# symfony 3.4 Route annotation requirements based on user input

Tags: php, symfony

I want allow user to perform search query with this URL
`mydomain.com/search/my+search`.

Problem is I can't use `path()` in twig to generate my form url's action because I can't guess my user's search and I got this error.

> Some mandatory parameters are missing ("fulltext") to generate a URL for route

I want this route only available if user tries to search something, so searchquery parameter can't be `empty` neither `null`.

There is a way to achieve that using symfony ? I could indeed use javascript to dynamically change my form's action but it doesn't prevent user to acces `mydomain.com/search/` without surbmitting form.

Search.html.twig

```html
<form action="{{ path('search') }}" method="get">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search" name="searchQuery">
  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="search" />
</form>
```

searchController.php

```php
/**
 * @Route("/search/{searchquery}", name="search", methods={"GET"}, requirements={
 *   "searchquery" = "([\w' \x22-\+]+)"
 * })
 */
 public function searchAction(Request $request){
  // Do stuff
 }
```

Comment: And what do you want to do if that search *is* empty? How do you handle that case? Because it's always a possibility with a GET action.

Comment: I think I should redirect to home page or display a flash message or something else but I can't perform a search accross all the database

Comment: Then you should not put a requirement in your route definition, but rather accept empty values and handle that case internally in the action (redirect if empty, perform search if not). I'm talking about directly accessing the url, the form should be validated to prevent empty inputs.

Comment: Ok I'll find a workound. But, how use `path('search')` in twig ? Event removing requirements error about mandatory params still persists. Should I use `defaults={"searchquery" = ""}` in route definition ?

Comment: And how reach url `mydomain.com/search/my+search` as I can't guess user input ?

Comment: Why do you feel like you need to guess? Submit the form to the base url and extract the search value from the request. It's then that you will perform the search and redirect the user to the result page which will have that slug filled with the searched value.

Comment: It will not perform request when user goes on mydomain.com/search/my+search+somethingelse. You could have a look to https://www.shutterstock.com/ to see what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to guess the parameter. You can achieve what you want by handling the form submission to the base `/search` route. I've created a dummy example using these two templates (index has the search form):

```
// index
{% block body %}
    <h1>You are on the main page</h1>
    <form action="{{ path('search') }}" method="post">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search" name="searchQuery">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="search" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Note that I've changed the form method to POST to avoid query parameters being tacked onto the url with `?`.

```
// search
{% block title %} Search {% endblock title %}
{% block body %}
    <p>You have searched for <b>{{ searchQuery }}</b></p>
{% endblock %}
```

Actions in the controller:

```php
/**
 * @Route("/", name="index")
 */
public function index()
{
    return $this->render('index.html.twig');
}

/**
 * @Route(
 *     "/search/{searchQuery}",
 *     name="search",
 *     defaults={"searchQuery" = ""},
 *     requirements={"searchQuery"=".+"}
 * )
 */
public function search(string $searchQuery, Request $request)
{
    // here we handle the form submission
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $searchQuery = $request->request->get('searchQuery');
        // checking this condition in case an empty field is submitted
        // though really the form should be validated to prevent this
        if ($searchQuery === '') {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('index');
        }
        // redirecting to the same action but with slug
        // to get an url with the desired form
        return $this->redirectToRoute(
            'search',
            ['searchQuery' => urlencode($searchQuery)]
        );
    }
    // this prevents accessing "/search/" path without a search query
    if ($searchQuery === '') {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('index');
    }
    // display search page if we actually have a search
    return $this->render(
        'search.html.twig',
        ['searchQuery' => urldecode($searchQuery)]
    );
}
```

This way if the search query is entered directly into the url, it will be picked up by the slug, for example `/search/military+equipment` will output:

> You have searched for **military equipment**

When the form is submitted, the parameter is extracted from the request and then we redirect the user to an url shaped as though the search query has been entered as a slug and the same thing happens.

The `requirements={"searchQuery"=".+"}` option tells Symfony to match any character (this allows the capture of paths `/search`, `/search/` or `/search/something`). Because of `defaults={"searchQuery" = ""}`, the first two will be treated as though the slug is an empty string (and thus redirected to the main page per our instructions in the search action).

This is just a quick and dirty proof of concept (with a bad user experience), you can refine your application's flow according to your desires and needs.